# Resultado duplicado no MySQL no while

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

A tabela tem duas colunas, uma de dados do usuário e outra de pontos do usuário, a pontos do usuário funciona como o esquema de extrato bancário, porém preciso que retorne apenas o último valor, e fiz assim

```
SELECT `usuario`.*, `pontos`.`ponto_valor` FROM `usuario` INNER JOIN `pontos` ON `pontos`.`ponto_id_user` = `usuario`.`user_id` ORDER BY `usuario`.`data_cad` DESC, `pontos`.`data_cad` DESC;
```

E fiz um WHILE com PHP para isso:

```
<?php
$instrucaoSQL = "SELECT 
                `usuario`.*, 
                `pontos`.`ponto_valor` 
            FROM 
                `usuario` 
            INNER JOIN 
                `pontos` 
            ON 
                `pontos`.`ponto_id_user` = `usuario`.`user_id` 
            ORDER BY 
                `usuario`.`data_cad` 
                    DESC,
                `pontos`.`data_cad`
                    DESC;";

$instrucaoQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $instrucaoSQL);

$contaQuery = mysqli_num_rows($instrucaoQuery);

if($contaQuery > 0) {

    while ( $r = mysqli_fetch_array($instrucaoQuery) ) {

        echo $r['user_nome'] . " - " . $r['ponto_valor'] . "<br>";

    }
?>
```

Porém o resultado vem tudo duplicado, gostaria que somente o último valor (linha) da tabela 'pontos' fosse exibida, sem duplicar os nomes da tabela 'usuario' toda vez que encontrar um valor relacionado na tabela 'pontos'.

Comment: Esse $r é o que?

Comment: é array, que recebe resultados do banco de dados, mas resolvi, valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi meu SQL assim:

```
$instrucaoSQL = "
            SELECT 
                `usuario`.*,
                `pontos`.`ponto_valor`
            FROM 
                `usuario` 
            INNER JOIN
                `pontos`
            ON
                `pontos`.`ponto_id_user` = `usuario`.`user_id`
               WHERE
                (
                SELECT 
                    `ponto_valor`
                ORDER BY
                    `pontos`.`data_cad`
                        DESC
                LIMIT 1
                )
             GROUP BY
                `usuario`.`user_nome`
                        ";
```